# Cannot run command in Docker container

Tags: docker, centos, redhat

I'm trying to execute `bash` in my docker container called "bind" via

```
docker exec -it bind bash
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: 
container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:110: 
decoding init error from pipe caused \"read parent: connection reset by peer\""
```

There's nothing extraordinary in the logs. Restarting docker or the container seemed to have no effect. I also made sure that there's enough space on the hard drive. Starting any other binary in the container yields the same error.

version info:

```
docker --version:

Docker version 1.13.1, build 07f3374/1.13.1
```

OS:

```
cat /etc/redhat-release 

CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's a bind running inside, and yes, there is a bash. Trying to run any command (e.g. "sh") inside yields the same result.

Comment: What is the base image?

Comment: Please post the command you used to start the container, as well (`docker run …`  or `docker-compose up …`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to be a bug introduced in a recent update to the docker RPM packages. A temporary workaround is to downgrade all docker packages to a previous release (75 seems to work).

```
yum downgrade docker-1.13.1-75.git8633870.el7_5 \
              docker-client-1.13.1-75.git8633870.el7_5 \
              docker-common-1.13.1-75.git8633870.el7_5 \
              docker-rhel-push-plugin-1.13.1-75.git8633870.el7_5
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the bug report on Red Hat's bugzilla : https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1655214

Answer (score 2):

if you use

```
yum update
```

before and no idea for what the old version of docker, just run

```
yum downgrade docker docker-client docker-common
```

it work for me

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue and has been fixed in newer docker packages:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1655214

For those with issues who cannot upgrade yet there is a workaround mentioned by William Brown in the issue that does not require a downgrade.

```
PID=docker inspect --format {{.State.Pid}} <name of container>
nsenter --target $PID --mount --uts --ipc --net --pid /bin/sh
```

Hope this works for you

Answer (score 1):

Today I installed an update of docker (version 1.13.1-84 on Centos) and since then I also have the same problem for all of my containers.

Downgrading to version 1.13.1-75 worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because of lack of permissions.

Try running docker with sudo like below.

> sudo docker exec -it bind bash

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, this is not the reason.

Answer (score 0):

"Connection reset by peer", generally happens when there is a certain mismatch of ports. Like you have not exposed a port and trying to use it, or, improper port mappings. In fact if, it is service a being binded to localhost, please check it, because if you want to host a service, you might want to bind it to 0.0.0.0

This error could relate to quite a lot of issues. but, predominantly, it concords with binding wrong ports and, wrong IPs.

Comment: It is bound to 0.0.0.0. The only ports being forwarded are 53 and 10000. The bind inside the container works as well. It's only that I cannot docker exec into the container.

Comment: Thanks for that info Fang, can you please let me know how whats the command. ideally, it should be, docker exec -it "container_name" bash . in this case, you need to make sure, the container, should allow bash. can you please comment the same

Comment: I am seeing the same today. Just spun on a vanilla nginx on a clean VM. Running "docker exec test id" yields the same error. I am running Linux 3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64 and Docker 1.13.1.